# Is there a downloadable spreadsheet of all known subatomic particles?

Tags: particle-physics, data

Is [this Wiki page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Subatomic_particles) complete in its list of subatomic particles? Looking for a CSV or spreadsheet I can download and easily translate into code of all the possible subatomic particles. [This page](https://indico.cern.ch/event/570855/contributions/2315628/attachments/1497944/2331728/I_-_Particles.pdf) says "100's of subatomic particles exist", if that's the case, where can I find a reasonably complete list for download and easy parsing/consumption i.e. ideally not a PDF which is too hard to copy/paste). I'm trying to look [here](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/listings/contents_listings.html) but not finding the 100's, and not finding a downloadable spreadsheet.

Comment: The PDG does have hundreds of particles. For example on the link you posted, if you click on Baryons/N Baryons, there are something like 30 resonances (particles) listed below a mass of 3000 MeV.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Particle Data Group provides a computer-readable file with the basic properties of the particles: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/mcdata/mass_width_2022.txt.
It however includes only particles which have been studied sufficiently well with their properties established to a good precision, and you will not find there many of the recently-discovered hadronic bound states such as pentaquarks. See in particular the list of particles discovered *at the LHC* here: [https://www.nikhef.nl/~pkoppenb/particles.html](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Epkoppenb/particles.html), which on its own has more than 60 items.

The summary of **all** known particles is found in human-readable pdf format here: https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/tables/contents_tables.html

There also exists a `particle` python package which is based on the txt file above: https://pypi.org/project/particle/

Comment: Didn't you notice the column labeled "name"?